# SQL Query using birth dates

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to find how many students between the ages of 25-29 are currently EXCLUDED on the registration system for being over 25.

Tables are: `STUDENT` & `STUDENT_STATUS_HISTORY`

`Student` contains `PERSON_ID` & `BIRTH_DATE` among other fields.
`Student_Status_History` contains `REASON_CODE` (excluded being 4)

My question regards the syntax for joining the tables and how to calculate the age range required correctly using the birth date.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Does `Student_Status_History` contain a person_ID column as well? If so, join on that. Subtract the date of birth from the current date, and you should get the number of days old they are. Divide by 365 to find the number of years old they are. Finally, check to see if the result is between 25 and 29.

Comment: @OP : you want number of students or want to return records also?

Comment: Number of students is fine.

Comment: @Bridge : Can you provide the syntax for your explanation? Thanks.

Comment: @GrumP I'm afraid I'm no Oracle expert, which is why I just gave the method rather than the specific implementation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
select count(*) from student s join student_status_history ssh 
on 
   s.id=ssh.student_id
where 
  ss.reason_code=4 
and 
  DATEDIFF(year,s.birthdate,sysdate)>=25 and DATEDIFF(year,s.birthdate,sysdate)<=29
```

See [DateDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

**EDIT** If DATEDIFF is not supported by your DB , try below:

```
select count(*) 
from 
  student s 
join 
  student_status_history ssh 
on 
   s.id=ssh.student_id
where 
  ss.reason_code=4 
and 
  floor(months_between(s.birthdate, sysdate) /12)>=25 and
  floor(months_between(s.birthdate, sysdate) /12)<=29
```

Comment: There is no `age` column, you have to work it out from the `BIRTH_DATE` column.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted, but it's probably using `DateDiff` - OP is using Oracle where this function doesn't exist.

Comment: @Bridge : I didn't point on you.:)  I didn't knew OP use Oracle. I have added option of DateDiff in updated answer.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi Thanks for this.  However, it does not return any results even if I widen the age gap to search.  Oracle version 11.1.0.7.0 11G Enterprise if it makes any difference?  It looks correct, and runs, but doesn't return data.  I know there is suitable records though.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi your code was almost correct, I reversed the position of s.birth_date, sysdate.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

JOIN the tables on PERSON_ID.

To get the birth date use a function like date difference:

```
select  trunc((months_between(sysdate, dob))/12) age
```